# How to count characters that appear twice consecutively

Tags: c++, string, windows

I'm using C++. So far, my code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char word[100]; int ctr, count = 0;
    printf("Enter string: "); gets(word);

    ctr = 1;
    while (word[ctr] != '\0') {
        if (word[ctr-1] == word[ctr]) count++;
        ctr++;
    }

    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Run

```
Enter string: mississippi
3

Enter string: mmmmrrnzzz
6
```

I've got the first sample run correctly (mississippi) with only 3 characters appearing twice consecutively but not on the second sample run (mmmmrrnzzz) with output 6.

My problem is that, it should not be 6 but 4 instead. 1 for the first two consecutive m, another separate 1 for the next two consecutive m, 1 for r, and 1 for z. I want a separate count for the first "mm" and the second "mm" and also for the "zz" but I don't know how.

I'm a freshman and very new to programming. I wish I could explain better. I'm hoping you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: `if (word[ctr-1] == word[ctr]) {count++;ctr++;}`

Comment: your are checking letter by letter, thus with `mmmm` you start at the second `m` and find 3 matches not 2. Same for the `zzz`. If you want to count as you describe, you should also increase `ctr++` if you found a match

Comment: Solution on @Thomas comment  should work properly

Comment: @DanielSanchez I didn't catch your comment, do you mind rephrase it? :)

Comment: @Thomas, i just mean that your solution in the first comment should work :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez Oh! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In case of multiple couples like `mmmm` you need to make a double incrementation of your counter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
    char word[100]; 
    int ctr;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter string: "); 
    gets(word);
    int len = strlen(word);
    ctr = 1;
    while (ctr<len) {
        if (word[ctr-1] == word[ctr]) 
        {
            count++;
            ctr++;
        }
        ctr++;
    }

    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was changing ctr++ to ctr+2 at first lol now I understand that I needed double incrementation :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the program looks like a C program. In fact you are not using C++. You are using C.:) At least for example in C++ you should use header

```
#include <cstdio>
```

instead of

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and so on.

And moreover it has a bug because in general the string can be empty. In this case the condition of the loop skips the first zero-terminating character and the program has undefined behaviour.

Here is a correct approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "mmmmrrnzzz";

    size_t count = 0;

    while ( *s++ )
    {
        if ( *s == *( s - 1) )
        {
            ++count;
            ++s;
        }
    }

    printf( "count = %zu\n", count );
}
```

The output is

```
count = 4
```

Take into account that function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C (or C++) Standard any more.

You should use function `fgets` instead of `gets`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char word[100]; int ctr, count = 0;
    printf("Enter string: "); gets(word);
    int len=strlen(word);
    ctr = 1;
    while (ctr<len) {
        if (word[ctr-1] == word[ctr]) 
        {
        count++;
        ctr++;
        }
        ctr++;
    }

    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard library version:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
  int count{};
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;

  for (auto it = s.begin(); (it = std::adjacent_find(it, s.end())) != s.end(); it += 2)
    ++count;

  std::cout << count << '\n';
}
```